# unknow exception is coming for the program

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, multidimensional-array

my program is intended for allocating a memory for an 2d array at run time and then take elements into it and then display it. my prog is throwing some exception can anyone help me identify it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{


int i,j,row, col;
    int *ptr;
    printf("enter size of row and col\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&row,&col);
    ptr = (int *)malloc(row*col*sizeof(int));
    if(ptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("stderr, not able to allocate memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("enter the element");
        for(i=0; i<row;i++)
            for(j=0;j<col;j++)
            {
              scanf("%d",ptr[i+j]);

            }
        for(i=0; i<row;i++)
        {   
            for(j=0;j<col;j++)
                printf("%d ",ptr[i+j]);
            printf("\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",ptr[i+j]);` what does this do?

Comment: Please post the actual error you are getting.

Comment: Run it in a debugger, and see where it fails.

Comment: I feel you're in the serious need of going through the relevant part of a decent C tutorial again.

Answer (score 1):

As Alok correctly guessed your issue is in your invocation of `scanf`

```
scanf("%d",ptr[i+j]);
```

For `scanf` you need to pass the address of the variable, not the variable itself. You can do either of the below to fix your code.

```
scanf("%d",&ptr[i+j]);

scanf("%d",(ptr+i+j));
```

p.s. minor nit, in the eyes of the compiler, you are allocating a 1D array, it is only in its use that you are accessing it as if it were a 2d array.

p.p.s As PaulR points out, you should use &ptr[i*col+j] to properly simulate a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` takes pointers to its arguments since it needs to modify them. Thus,

```
scanf("%d", ptr[i + j]);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d", &ptr[i + j]);
```

or

```
scanf("%d", ptr + i + j);
```

instead.

(If you're really intending to emulate a two-dimensional array, then you should use

```
&ptr[i * columns + j]
```

anyway - thanks to PaulR for pointing that out.)

Comment: More likely it's meant to be `&ptr[i * col + j]`?

Comment: Guys I know that I'm using one Dimensional method for traversing 2-d array. My thought was, why do i need pointer to2-d array  when I can do it with pointer to 1-d array. Also thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Your access to the presumably intended as two-dimensional array `ptr` is very suspect, it should go something like `ptr[row * i + j]` each time (after fixing the mess with `scanf` mentioned in the other answer).